# incorrect data update in the Heroku database

Tags: sqlite, heroku

I came across an interesting problem, I needed a small api for 2 pages and a small database. I wrote it all quickly in Django using a sqlite file to store the data, since it is quite simple and I don't have much data in the database. I put all this on a free host from Heroku, since it is all very economical in terms of resources, and I also do not need any domain settings, etc., and faced the problem that when I make certain changes in the database through the admin panel, they are first displayed in api, but every day they are rolled back to the database that is in my github, now I have disabled the autodeploy of branches because I suspect that it may be related to some automatic updates, maybe someone has encountered such a problem and can give me advice?